# What does new[] mean?

Tags: c#

Cannot hit one when search like "c# new followed by square braces", etc:

```
var dialog = new ABCDialog{
 Title = xxxx,
 Content = ...
};

dialog.Buttons = new[] { dialog.OkButton };
```

Buttons are like IEnumerable Buttons {get;set;}
OkButton is a getter.

Thanks!

Comment: It just creates an array with the given values, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array initialization syntax.  You're creating a new array that looks like:   `Button[]` with one item `dialog.OkButton` inside of it.